# Authentication to TFS Service fails from WinForms in VS2010

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, authentication, tfs

In my .Net windows application (a code generator) I want to check out files programmaticaly from a TFS service. Although I can access and checkout files in VS2010 from the TFS Service without any problems, my program always returns

> "TF30064: You are not authorized to access the server"

I have tried numerous things, something like this:

```
var account = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password);
tfs.TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = 
    new tfs.TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(anUrl), account);
teamProjectCollection.Authenticate();
```

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running you application as yourself, and you have access to TFS, then you can just do:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/MyCollection");
using (var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(uri))     
{         
    tfs.EnsureAuthenticated(); 
    //Your code goes here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: [Connect to Team Foundation Server from a Console Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb286958.aspx).

It says about a console application, but you can use all tips in your WinForm app as well.

In special, this part in (Acting on Behalf of Another User (Impersonation)):

> Using Authenticated Credentials
>
> You can use an ICredentials object
> when you connect to Team Foundation Server to specify the identity to
> impersonate. This strategy does not require special permissions, but
> you must be able to obtain the password of the identity to create the
> ICredentials object. You can also specify an implementation of
> ICredentialsProvider when you connect to Team Foundation Server to
> handle requests for new credentials. The system calls the
> implementation of ICredentialsProvider that you specify to request new
> credentials when the credentials that are specified by the
> ICredentials object are not successfully authenticated or authorized
> to perform the operation. To prompt the user for credentials, you can
> use the UICredentialsProvider class, which implements
> ICredentialsProvider by displaying a logon dialog box to prompt the
> user for new credentials.

Comment: Thanks Rafael,
 for making me aware of this example.